# Android open source game engines + tutorials

Tags: android, open-source, game-engine

Hey iam pretty new to the android platform and wondering what the best open source game engine is and ples link some tutorials.

i just want to make something like a simple 2d platformer

ThX =)

Comment: You need to tell first what your objectives are, what type of games you want to build, as for some simple games, some engines are overkill.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to have to plug Andengine - http://www.andengine.org/

It's free, it's open (source included) and it offers extensions for Box2D Physics, Live Wallpapers, Aug. Reality (Camera games) and allsorts of other stuff - LOADS of game in the market using it already (no royalties)

Downside is that the documentation is patchy (it's basically a lot of examples) and the author now works for Zynga and has been awfully quiet since he got a proper job :(

You can do amazing things with it tho - and it's easier than most of it's alternatives.

Unity - lovely idea but Unity-based Android Apps are horribly bloated.

If you already 'speak' Open/GL and/or you like the idea of developing/deploying on PC as well as Android, there's libgdx too - http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/
Andengine sort of sits on-top of that anyway - it's harder-work to learn but obviously being able to test/deploy on PC as well as Android has it's benefits.

Comment: +1 for this answer, go for libgdx, No docs for andengine

Comment: libgdx is now moved to github - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.cuteandroid.com/ten-open-source-android-2d-or-3d-game-engine-for-android-developers) is a list.

Many people recommend [Cocos-2d](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

I mostly recommend [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) as it is simply awesome! It has a great [documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/) and many [resources and tutorials](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/). But for Android development, it is not free. [Here](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) is the price details and comparison of features.

Comment: The first link connects to something completely unrelated to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend libgdx ! best fps out of all of them!

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html